# When to use an IIS 6 Website vs. Virtual Directory

Tags: iis, configuration, iis-6

I can create a Website in IIS 6 just fine. But can't find out how to browse to it. I created a Website called TestWebSite and I try
    `http://myservername/TestWebsite`
but it does not work. 
But if I create a virtual directory under my website called TestVirtual I can browse to it. 
Why can't I browse to the Websitename?

Comment: Do you have the default website (or any other) started?

Comment: Yes, there is a default website, I added my website in the same tree it was in.

Comment: Perhaps both websites are configured with the same ip/port combination?